# Deleting a line in a big file - should I avoid doing it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858206/find-string-in-a-txt-file-delete-entire-line) about deleting a specific line in a file in node.js, and what they're doing is splitting data by `\n` in an array, deleting one element, recreating a string with join, and overwriting the file with the result.

That's fine for "normal" files, but mine is ~50,000 lines long and growing, and I don't think it's a good idea to put all that in an array, delete stuff and trust the result enough to overwrite the file.

- Basically I want to check random lines periodically, and delete them if a condition isn't met. Is it safe or should I avoid doing that ? If it's ok, is there another way to do it, more appropriate for big files ?

**A little background:** The file is written on every X minutes, and I know when it's safe to edit. My goal is to check+delete a small enough number of lines so that I'm sure it'll be done before the next writing. I can also pause the writing if I want to do a complete check.

Comment: That's how files are working. If you want to change/delete something, you've to re-write the whole file. 50,000 lines is actually not much. If possible, you could store the data in a JSON file, though it has to be re-written too. An alternative is to store the data into a database.

Comment: @Teemu So javascript is fine with making and copying 50k-elements arrays ?

Comment: There was a post here at SO for a while ago, OP loaded 46MB JSON, that's big = ). An array having 50000 "lines" really isn't large, the maximum size is 2^32-1.

Comment: How are you be sure you'll be done loading, changing, and writing the file contents before the next regular writing? Sounds fragile to me. I would use a database or at least file locks in the deleting and the appending part.

Comment: @BlackJack Yes, I am sure. I can always make the regular writing every 10 minutes if I'm not sure. I don't want to use a database (it would make the whole thing meaningless), but if you have a safer solution with file locks I'm all ears.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: Is the deleting part synced to that 10 minutes interval? How? Why would a database make the program meaningless? Regarding locks: Seems one needs an external package to have `flock()` available, for instance [fs-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-ext).

Comment: @BlackJack the deleting part is not synced to anything, I run it manually when my file is (partially) corrupted, and it's pretty rare. I would do it manually but the file is pretty big and I have to check a condition on each line, I figured I could do that with a script, even for a one-time thing. It turned out I used it more than once. The file is about monitoring a database so I don't want to have it in a database too. I could, but the goal is to manipulate its content easily.